# Suitable subject name for ADFS certificate

Tags: azure, certificate, ssl-certificate, adfs, windows-server-2012-r2

I'm running the Azure AD connect Wizard and on the following page I have to give a self-signed certificate for AD FS. But I get the error

`The certificate does not have a suitable subject name.`

[image]

I'm creating the certificate using IIS. Anyone can help me with creating a good self-signed certificate for this step?

Comment: Don't use the machine name. Something like login.adfs.company.com?

Answer (score 1):

use the federation service name, ex. fs.contoso.com which is the name of the ADFS Service

Comment: Which do you use for creating a self signed certificate? With IIS I can't give a subject name

Comment: get a cert from a public trusted CA. https://www.wosign.com/english/ and https://www.startssl.com/ both offer free certs. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn151311.aspx explains the necessity of a cert from a publicly trusted root. Don't use self signed certs.

Comment: for the federation service at least don't use self signed certificates. You can but not recommended. For token signing certificates you can use self signed certificates, in fact that is something that most of the ADFS deployments do.